# Importing sweetalert: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, sweetalert

I am trying to import `sweetalert` component into existing typescript file to replace current *alert* function.

I did following:

- copy `sweetalert.min.js` into into `scripts` folder.
- add reference to `index.html`:
- downloaded `typings` into "./node_modules/sweetalert/typings/sweetalert.d.ts"
- my `tsconfig.json`:

  "target": "es2015",
  "module": "es2015",
  "esModuleInterop": true,
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  .....
  "files": [
  "./node_modules/sweetalert/typings/sweetalert.d.ts",
  etc...
- typescript file: added "`import swal from 'sweetalert'`"

While compile works, I get error in Chrome browser:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement otside a module.

Do I have to make module out of my typescript file? Or any other way to declare variable swal without import statement?
If I just omit import statement, I get compile errors on swal statement:

> This expression is not callable.   Type 'typeof
> import("c:/xampp/htdocs/gui/node_modules/sweetalert/typings/sweetalert")'
> has no call signatures.ts(2349) module swal var swal: typeof
> import("c:/xampp/htdocs/gui/node_modules/sweetalert/typings/sweetalert")

(In this project I have also pure js file that uses swal and it work normally).
Any idea?

br

Comment: try change "module" from "es2015" to "commonjs"

Comment: If I change to commonjs, I get: 
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined.

Comment: I solved these problems by converting files to modules, for example:

<script ***type = "module"*** src = "script/serverProxy.js"></script>

Comment: Now I get:  `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "sweetalert". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`